# Using the Norm Function

Tags: vector, algebraic-manipulation, dot

I am trying to take the norm of a general vector and show that for vectors, **v**,**w**, that

Norm[v cross w]^2==Norm[v]^2*Norm[w]^2-(v dot w)^2

In Mathematica, here are my steps:

```
v = {v1, v2, v3}
w = {w1, w2, w3}
q = Simplify[Norm[v]^2,
p = Simplify[Norm[w]^2,
x = Simplify[Dot[v, w]^2]
a = Simplify[Expand[q*p - x]]
z = Cross[v, w]
y = Norm[z]^2
y == a
```

However in computing the Norms of the vector, it gives me Abs[v1], Abs[v2], Abs[v3], etc. Any idea on how to remove it? Or should I define the elements of the vectors to be real numbers?

Comment: Is this expression the expression you are actually entering into *Mathematica*? If so, `v cross w` is interpreted as multiplying the symbols `v`, `cross`, and `w`. If not, please edit your post with your actual code.

Comment: No, not at all. I am doing it step by step. One moment

Comment: Well, I posted a quick answer. Let me know if more details are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining the vectors:

```
v1 = Array[v, 3]
v2 = Array[w, 3]
(* {v[1], v[2], v[3]} *)
(* {w[1], w[2], w[3]} *)
```

Then:

```
Cross[v1, v2].Cross[v1, v2] - (v1.v1 v2.v2 - (v1.v2)^2) // Expand
(* 0 *)
```

Note that in general, when doing algebraic manipulations, it is better to use the explicit form of the squared-norm of a vector, because `Norm` is interpreted in terms of `Abs` which does not automatically simplify because *Mathematica* assumes all symbols are `Complex` unless told otherwise. In other words, use `Sqrt[v.v]` instead of `Norm[v]` and `v.v` instead of `Norm[v]^2`.

Comment: instead of v2 can I just use w1? I dont see why not

Comment: Sure, use `w1` instead of `v2`. Call the variables whatever you want. However, you should avoid `v = Array[v, 3]` because you will get an infinite recursion. Your code above is fine, except that you want to avoid using `Norm`. I was just showing you another way of doing it.